# only show records if userid is in table

Tags: mysql

Ok lets imagine I have a table called `following`

In this table it looks like this

```
userid   networkid
9          42
10         36
```

then I have a table called feeds

```
postedby     post 

42           Meow!
```

Using a sql query how can I first check the table for following, then show the posts from the feed table where postedby matches the networkid that user 9 is following.

Hope this makes more sense.

Comment: You mean `f.type = 'user'` instead of `type = 'user'`, etc? We don't have the luxury of knowing what your tables look like. I also miss a quote at the end, typo in the question?

Comment: Do you need 'the best way', or just 'a way'? Either way, see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Look into joins. Sounds like a simple case.

Answer (score 0):

Should be like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM following
JOIN feeds ON feeds.postedby = following.networkid
WHERE following.userid = 9
```